# Local System Drives not opening within the same window in XP

Tags: windows-xp

All my drives are not opening within the same window instead opens in a new window... I have done

- view->FolderOptions->Open within the
- same window

nothing worked.. I even tried unchecking

- ControlPanel-> FolderOptions-> Launch
- Folder windows in separate process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

Locate the Default value under the following key in the registry:

**HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell**

Modify the **Default** key and type **none** as it's value, click OK, and exit the registry editor

Comment: @Mark it didnt help me....

Answer (score 1):

1. Open **Start** >> **Run** and type `regsvr32 /i shell32.dll`
2. press **OK**

Comment: @Molly it didnt work